# Two-Dimensional Loop OutOfBoundsException - Java

Tags: java

I was wondering if you guys could help me out with some of my code. I have been programming this puzzle creator, but when I attempt to generate values for my two-dimensional array, I get an OutOfBoundsException. I'm sure this solution is simple, but for whatever reason, I can't seem to find what's wrong. (Also, of course, there is a driver class that goes along with this, but I don't think that's necessary to include here.)

```
import java.util.*;

public class ThirtyWonderful 
{
    private int dimen;

    public ThirtyWonderful (int dimensions)
    {
        dimen = dimensions;
    }

    public ThirtyWonderful()
    {
        dimen = 5;
    }

    Random gen = new Random();
    int[][] nums = new int [dimen][dimen];

    public void genPuzzle()
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < dimen; count++)
        {   
            for(int col = 0; col < dimen; col++)
            {
                nums[count][col] = gen.nextInt(9) + 1;
            }
        }
        checkAcc();

        if(checkAcc() == true)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < dimen; count++)
            {     
                for(int col = 0; col < dimen; col++)
                {
                    System.out.print(nums[count][col] + " ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }  

    public boolean checkAcc()
    {
        int tot = 0;
        for (int count = 0; count < dimen; count++)
        {   
            for(int col = 0; col < dimen; col++)
            {
                tot += nums[count][col];
            }

            if(tot != 31)
                return false;
        }

        for (int count = 0; count < dimen; count++)
        {   
            for(int col = 0; col < dimen; col++)
            {
                tot += nums[count][col];
            }

            if(tot != 31)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring nums with new int [dimen][dimen]; Before dimen even initialization, By default dimen value is 0, so nums is initialize with new int[0][0]

Here is the Fix Code

```
public class ThirtyWonderful {

    private int dimen;

    Random gen = new Random();
    int[][] nums;

    public ThirtyWonderful(int dimensions) {
        this.dimen = dimensions;
        nums = new int[dimen][dimen];
    }

    public ThirtyWonderful() {
        this(5);
    }

    public void genPuzzle() {
        for (int count = 0; count < dimen; count++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < dimen; col++) {
                nums[count][col] = gen.nextInt(9) + 1;
            }
        }
        checkAcc();

        if (checkAcc() == true) {
            for (int count = 0; count < dimen; count++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < dimen; col++) {
                    System.out.print(nums[count][col] + " ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkAcc() {
        int tot = 0;
        for (int count = 0; count < dimen; count++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < dimen; col++) {
                tot += nums[count][col];
            }

            if (tot != 31) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int count = 0; count < dimen; count++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < dimen; col++) {
                tot += nums[count][col];
            }

            if (tot != 31) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course, my program won't run work because of a logical error... but that's a separate issue XD

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize your array object in your constructors. you are initializing your array at class load time before your object is instantiated.